# ionic modal get error to open : ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new in Ionic framework. I try to open Modal on click. But it get a run time error.

**page.html**

```
<ion-icon ios="ios-add" md="md-add" class="p-info-btn" (click)="presentModal()"></ion-icon>
```

**page.ts**

```
export class ResumePage {
    constructor( public modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

    presentModal() {
        let modal = this.modalCtrl.create('PersonalInformationFormPage');
        modal.present();
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad ResumePage');
    }
}
```

**Error:**

```
Runtime Error
Uncaught (in promise): invalid link: PersonalInformationFormPage
```

**PersonalInformationFormPage:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@Component({ 
    selector: 'page-personal-information-form',
    templateUrl: 'personal-information-form.html'
})
export class PersonalInformationFormPage { 
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams){ }
    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad PersonalInformationFormPage'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your `PersonalInformationFormPage`-module?

Comment: u mean app.module.ts ?

Comment: If you don't want lazy loading just remove the `'` `let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(PersonalInformationFormPage);`  Given that you have declared your page correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you pass a `string` to `modalCtrl.create()` you are lazy loading the page/modal. Then your modal should have its own module. Or be passed in to `IonicPageModule.forChild()` in a module that declares more pages/components.

Make sure your `personal-information-form-page.module.ts` looks something like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { PersonalInformationFormPage } from './personal-information-form-page';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(PersonalInformationFormPage)
    ],
    declarations: [
        PersonalInformationFormPage
    ]
})
export class PersonalInformationFormPageModule{}
```

And add the `@IonicPage`-decorator to your page:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core'; 
import { NavController, NavParams, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular'; 

@IonicPage(),
@Component({ 
    selector: 'page-personal-information-form',
    templateUrl: 'personal-information-form.html'
})
export class PersonalInformationFormPage { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: no its not like this. it havn't @NgModule function. how to create module by command?

Comment: it like this:
`import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-personal-information-form',
  templateUrl: 'personal-information-form.html',
})
export class PersonalInformationFormPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad PersonalInformationFormPage');
  }

}`

Comment: Somehow your application doesn't recognise your modal. You have to look at how you declare it.

Comment: In what module have you declared your modal, please add code for that module in your question.

Comment: Is there any mistake in my question please check it and tell me what i am doing wrong?

Comment: The only error i se is the one I pointed out, your passing a string to the `this.modalCtrl.create()´-function. But that is only a mistake if you don't intend to lazy load the modal.

Comment: thank you. found error and fix it. it works perfect now

Comment: @JamalAhmad can you explain the fix, please?